# using ffmpeg lib in visual studio(error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, static-libraries

I'm trying build a example project with ffmpeg lib and a websocketlib, but i received this error:

[image: Error Message]

the message says

`"The program can not be started because it is missing avcodec-56.dll on your computer. Try to reinstall it to solve this problem."`

EDIT: in console i received this message:

```
** 'A dependent dll was not found'.**
```

how i edit dependent path?

EDIT2:i solved the problem, i added the dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: ***how i edit dependent path?*** Edit your PATH environment variable in your OS. http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: I'm talking about changing the dll path but I do not know what the dll ;(

Comment: You already said what dll it was: `avcodec-56.dll` If you add the location of this dll to your system path variable (tells windows where to look for executables and dlls) and reboot the you should not get this error the next time you run your program.

Comment: Or just put that dll in the same folder as your executable.

Comment: i solved the problem, i added the dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\, now i'm received other error cause dlls, but thanks man